# AWS DynamoDB permissions based on other data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there any way of controlling access to DynamoDB data based on data in other tables? By way of comparison, Firebase Realtime Database rules have access to a snapshot of the entire database when being evaluated, so rules like this are possible:

```
".write": "root.child('allow_writes').val() === true"
```

But all my reading of the AWS permissions structure hasn't given me any clue how to achieve the same thing. There are variables that can be tested based on the current authenticated user, and some variables based on the current request, but no way I can see of referencing other data within the database.

Comment: Is this you are looking at - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html

Comment: That's part of it. As far as I can see it only allows the userid to be used to control access - I need to be able to grant access for a given user to a set of resources, managed through the database itself. That's straightforward with Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS don't support this case, you're only option would be to put the access control in your application.

You can control table, item or attribute level data access in DynamoDB using a [IAM policy variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html). Frustratingly AWS don't even seem to publish a list of available policy variables. Typically it boils down to using Cognito sub or AWS userid, which the majority of people don't want to use as a partition keys in their tables.

Comment: Putting the access control in the app is an unacceptable security hole. I guess I'm sticking with Firebase for now.